# Is there way to find the even sum and odd sum from the numbers inputted by the user using a while loop?

Tags: python

I am new to python, and I just learned loops. I am trying to write a program that reads six integers and then finds the sum of the even and odd integers, using a while loop. I am not sure how to use the while loop in this situation.
This is what I started with:

```
print('Please enter 6 integers:')
n_1=int(input('>',))
n_2=int(input('>',))
n_3=int(input('>',))
n_4=int(input('>',))
n_5=int(input('>',))
n_6=int(input('>',))
Even_sum = 0
Odd_sum = 0
while
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use a `while` rather than a `for`? The latter makes more sense here (and in >95% of all cases in Python).

Comment: Variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of writing a line for each input you could use the while loop to keep getting inputs for n times (6 in your example). Also, it's better to initialise both sums at the very beginning and add to each of them every even or odd input that is given. You also need to define a counter or a boolean statement that will stop the loop.

```
sum_even = 0
sum_odd = 0
i=0
while i < 6:
    num = int(input())
    # check if input is even
    if (num % 2) == 0:
        sum_even+=num
    else:
        sum_odd+=num
    i+=1
```